# Read text from text file and display it line by line with the name of the field and its value

Tags: java

I have this text file:

```
1             Juan García12-11-2016                               Reparación caldera 110.50
2             Eva Blasco05-10-2016                                     Fuga de agua 200.00
3           Rosa Carreras23-01-2016                                  Cambio de filtro    0.75
```

And I need to display it like this on the console:

```
Code: 1, Client: Juan García, Date: 12-11-2016, Concept: Reparación caldera, Price: 110.50
```

I have tried to do it with regex but i usually get errors and i don't have time to properly learn it

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
            "^([\\d.]+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+([\\d.]+)\\s+(.+?)\\s+\\((\\d+)\\)(?:\\s+\\{([^{}]+))?"
    );
    Matcher m = p.matcher("");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Temp\\factura.txt"));
    while (sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        if (m.reset(s).find())
        {
            System.out.printf("%s %8s %6s%n%s (%s) %s%n%n",
                    m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4), m.group(5),
                    m.start(6) != -1 ? m.group(6) : "");
        }
    }
```

I tried some things with regex and substring but i can't get it to work and I'm going crazy with this.

Any help apreciated.

Comment: Is there a clear delimiter between fields on each line?  If so, `String.split()` would likely be most appropriate here.

Comment: Maybe the spaces between each field and the name and date are toghether, but maybe a number after a letter. Except that there are no delimiters, it's just a text file.

Comment: I'm starting to see that maybe String.split() may work. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line="1             Juan García12-11-2016                               Reparación caldera 110.50";

        String amount=line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(' '),line.length());
        String code=line.substring(0,line.indexOf(' '));
        String remaining=line.substring(code.length(),line.lastIndexOf(' '));
        //Juan García12-11-2016                               Reparación caldera
        remaining=remaining.trim();

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d").matcher(remaining);
        matcher.find();
        int i = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group());

        String name=remaining.substring(0,i);
        remaining=remaining.substring(name.length(),remaining.length());
        //12-11-2016                               Reparación caldera
        String date=remaining.split(" ")[0];
        String concept=remaining.substring(date.length(),remaining.length());
        concept=concept.trim();

        System.out.printf("code: "+code+" client:"+name+" Date:"+date+" Concept: "+concept+" Price:"+amount);

}
```

Comment: OMG, I love you!!. Thank you so much :D

Comment: kool and I love you too :)

Comment: but there are some errors, p.e: Client:Juan Garc�a-->1<--, Date:(¿1?)2-11-2016

Comment: @IvánIvanovMarín Looks like some UTF-8 characters. can u post this line here